# In Azure Synapse, how do I setup a SQL Server that can access Datalake Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse

I have setup a Synapse environment and filled my storage account with some sample Parquet files. I have then created a serverless SQL database and created some external tables over the Parquet files. All this works fine and I can query these tables fine from the Synapse UI and SSMS using AD Authentication.

The problem is I want to connect an app to the serverless SQL database which doesn't support AD authentication. Therefore I want to connect it using a standard SQL account. I have setup a SQL account (username and password) and I'm able to connect through SSMS, but not query any tables due to this error...

> External table 'TableName' is not accessible because content of directory cannot be listed.

I assume this is a double-hop authentication problem because the SQL user doesn't have access to the storage account? I can't seem to find any guides on how to do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a blog-post where this issue is tackled, as I've encountered this problem as well a few days ago.  You can read it [here](https://fgheysels.github.io/access-private-containers-from-synapse/).

Basically, it comes down to the fact that you have to:

- create a SQL login for your user
- create a credential in SQL that has the same name as the URL that points to the container in your datalake that contains the files you want to query
- grant reference rights on that credential to your SQL login
- create a user on your database for that login

Next to that, you also need to create some specific role-assignments.

Comment: Great article thanks. I've followed it to the letter, and still an error: Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://name.dfs.core.windows.net/data/', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: Where do you get that error ? When granting the reference permissions to that credential ?  If so, do you execute that statement while connected to the master database ?

Comment: @FrederikGheysels i followed all the steps from your blog, but now i can only connect to the master database and not to my lake database.